# Does a http POST request guarantee a specific response?

Tags: c#, http, http-headers

I'm trying to log into the website of my school using c#. Using the software Fiddler, I've managed to capture the post request my browser makes and the post request I've recreated in c#. They seem to be completly identical, however the response I get is different. Shouldn't the server theoretically respond the same way if the post request is the same, at least with the same status code? 
When I use my own client I get response code 200, but with my browser I get 303(which it should be).

Something I notice is that the WebForm content is much bigger in browser, but the values used in the client request are from a prior GET request. Sorry for the long post.

These are the requests captured by Fiddler:

**Browser request:**

POST https://www.lectio.dk/lectio/31/login.aspx HTTP/1.1

Host: www.lectio.dk
Connection: keep-alive

Content-Length: 881

Cache-Control: max-age=0

Origin: https://www.lectio.dk

Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36

Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3

Referer: https://www.lectio.dk/lectio/31/login.aspx

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br

Accept-Language: en-GB,en-AS;q=0.9,en-DK;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,da-DK;q=0.6,da;q=0.5,en-US;q=0.4

Cookie: LastLoginExamno=31; 
ASP.NET_SessionId=ANTOMFZ7ZZWAYYW52OSZQYRXIBAIEGIPGILQHQ6TEJ2O5XEUTE3CAIBA; isloggedin3=N

time=0&__EVENTTARGET=m%24Content%24submitbtn2&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__SCROLLPOSITION=&__VIEWSTATEX=vQAAAGlpZQk1NDg4MjIyMjVpbAJrAIFsAmhpZGwCZwJpbAJrAWUDb2ZmbASBaWRsAoFpZGwCgWlkbAJoaWpkam4BZQcyMDE5LzIwbgFlBDIwMTl%2BAXFsAWhkZwNpZGwCZwVpZGwCaGlkbAJnB2lkbAaBaWwCawJlFE4mIzIzMDtydW0gR3ltbmFzaXVtZGcFaWRsAoFpZGwCgWlsAmsDZQI1MGRnB2lkbAKBaWRsAoFpamlsAmsEcGRkZGRkBQAAABNWYWxpZGF0ZVJlcXVlc3RNb2RlDGF1dG9jb21wbGV0ZQlpbm5lcmh0bWwJbWF4bGVuZ3RoB0NoZWNrZWQAXXvzIZezMAoPCqv5j%2FZuNIu6H1E%3D&__VIEWSTATEY_KEY=&__VIEWSTATE=&__EVENTVALIDATION=CY6WRLYHybmNGyj0%2FWgw9s%2BaewM2gnWAIUbvnFzgoYWgYPLkQnxHIBIpQPjEa3On7opgtRStMA%2FpLhG9PzzgXNTaWwTZIeSfKwS74n4yMULKRovRw2H%2Fwlg8HRUdJemRR%2FyFEzIkbToD8psr4CO9G3nzX706D25SYrmTc2WygXZ%2B1oYTAMe3FD7ocBdwh%2FrHRBAOaoTzCsCSlpMVce8GxcWKS3lryh8E8yVmy4AgrHpjgj3R0g1ziPKG96%2B1vVr%2B&m%24Content%24username2=username&m%24Content%24passwordHidden=password&LectioPostbackId=

**C# client request:**

POST https://www.lectio.dk/lectio/31/login.aspx HTTP/1.1

Cache-Control: max-age=0

Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, application/xml; q=0.9, image/webp, image/apng, */*; q=0.8, application/signed-exchange; v=b3

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br

Accept-Language: en-GB, en-AS; q=0.9, en-DK; q=0.8, en; q=0.7, da-DK; q=0.6, da; q=0.5, en-US; q=0.4

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36

Referer: https://www.lectio.dk/lectio/31/login.aspx

Origin: https://www.lectio.dk

Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1

Connection: keep-alive

Cookie: LastLoginExamno=31; 
ASP.NET_SessionId=DBYVNKXMKMO2F7XF7T22TM4RALBLKYPBQT42BGZX6H2UA5TZ2ZHCAIBA

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Content-Length: 485

Host: www.lectio.dk

time=0&__EVENTTARGET=m%24Content%24submitbtn2&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__SCROLLPOSITION=&__VIEWSTATEX=FAAAAGlpZQotMTY2NzgzMzI1ZGQAAAAAALJLI4R47o%2FDmiaj2f9RNeeWl%2B5K&__VIEWSTATEY_KEY=&__VIEWSTATE=&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FYOJVoNfWl%2F8olHfFefQyPMhqxIUan914QzoN6cFD0eGMukIp%2B%2FciKjpJU04AgXJhME7LttuUGcP8yOJ7xPSSP%2Bl8AnZk2DAdvMIFLFAAPD2Rf4K1DapTvDcnWnyz%2Bj1tesSoSUmLcmmh2E0ljSNR1Qr%2BUpIWQ91RtL1jS4GDh0%3D&m%24Content%24username2=povl0057&m%24Content%24passwordHidden=jdf59jcx&LectioPostbackId=

Comment: Hope that username and password are just random strings and not your actual credentials...

Comment: You're passing a `SessionID` in the request, which more than likely has expired.

Comment: It looks like there is an eventvalidation part of the post. This needs to match what was sent back from the server with the previous Page’s get request. It is only good for 1 response and that response may need to come from the same IP address that the get was executed from. This means that you will first have to http “get” the form, parse the validation information, then post back with that validation key.   There is also session tags in the header. You may need to “login” to get a session tag that goes with your IP address and port.

Comment: The response can be whatever the server wants it to be.

Comment: The username and password are placeholders for privacy reasons, the values used in the WebForm and cookies come from a previous Http get request.

Answer (score 1):

> Shouldn't the server theoretically respond the same way if the post request is the same?

No

Comment: Maybe offer an explanation?

Comment: No. Server can respond whatever they want. That's pretty clear answer.

Comment: Hmm, could you perhaps elaborate? Is it not desirable for a server to respond in the same way?